# R - Convert latitude and longitude to grid numbers

Tags: r, machine-learning, coordinates

I'm currently doing a classification project and the data I'm using includes  lat/long attributes. In order to simply the model(s) I'm thinking it might be easier to replace the raw coordinates with a single column of 'grid' numbers.

By this I mean chop-up the area that the coordinates cover into an arbitrary number of grid points, number each square within the grid, and then replace the lat/long figures with the grid number which they fall in. For example, a 9 square grid might look like this:

```
123
456
789
```

I've done a fair bit of searching on here and Google and can't seem to find a solution. The closest I can find is the Universal Transverse Mercator coordinate system (which some R packages support), but the squares within this grid are too large. I'd like to be able to set the size of the grid myself.

I'm at a bit of a loss, and was wondering if the kind people of this forum knew of any R packages or techniques to achieve what I'd like. I'll append an example of my lat/long columns. Thanks.

```
Latitude    Longitude
41.95469    -87.800991
41.95469    -87.800991
41.994991   -87.769279
41.974089   -87.824812
41.974089   -87.824812
41.9216     -87.666455
41.891118   -87.654491
41.867108   -87.654224
41.867108   -87.654224
41.896282   -87.655232
41.919343   -87.694259
```

Comment: Have you tried `sp::point.in.polygon`? You can generate arbitrary polygons (that may be rectangular) and check all points.

Comment: I've run into similar challenges mapping census block interior points to a regular grid. In that case, I created a grid (expand.grid(lon = seq(-87.9, -87.6, 0.1), lat = seq(41.8, 42, 0.66))) and then iterated through the original data frame and assigned each point in the original data frame to the closest member of the grid. Not elegant but it is functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not especially elegant, but this works

```
pos <- data.frame(lat=c(
41.95469,
41.95469,    
41.994991,   
41.974089,   
41.974089,   
41.9216,     
41.891118,   
41.867108,   
41.867108,   
41.896282,   
41.919343),   
long=c(
-87.824812,
-87.769279,
-87.800991,
-87.800991,
-87.824812,
-87.666455,
-87.654491,
-87.654224,
-87.654224,
-87.655232,
-87.694259))

gridx <- seq(from=-87.9,to=-87.6,by=0.01)
gridy <- seq(from=41.8,to=42,by=0.01)
xcell <- unlist(lapply(pos$long,function(x) min(which(gridx>x))))
ycell <- unlist(lapply(pos$lat,function(y) min(which(gridy>y))))
pos$cell <- (length(gridx) - 1) * ycell + xcell
```

Comment: That seems to do the job. Thanks you.